# Popups during post reviews

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, popups

Whenever you flag a post for moderator attention, there's a friendly "Thanks, we'll look into it." popup, which is fine.

However, it also shows up when you're doing [answer reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?subtype=notananswer), in which case it gets annoying after a few times, especially if it hangs hover the next post underneath it.

Is it possible to not show anything or only show a popup if the flag could not be submitted?

**Update**

It seems that this has been resolved with the smaller popup notifications. They don't overlap the next review task anymore :)